# Twilio sms StatusCallback url

Tags: spring-boot, twilio-api

what should be the method this  https://******/get-sms-activity  be used on
get method or post method, from twilio docs I found it's sending data through get method in the HttpServletRequest please tell what method to use?

```
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("StatusCallback","https://******/get-sms-activity" ));
```

Comment: How will twilio send data will it post a json object related to our message or will the HttpServletRequest object have the message status data?

Comment: Any twilio evangelist suggest me how to track the status of my sms sent